Earth woman takes alien lover with blue hair and blond eyes, has invisible baby
An earth woman and an alien man with blue hair and blond eyes fell in love on earth. When she gave birth in a hospital she could only see the baby by closing her eyes as he was invisible. I've always thought the title was 'Oh, You Ubiquitous You', but never found this title. The story was in a paperback science fiction anthology of different authors, read in early to mid 1960s.

If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Why, that's whom this woman was talking to in the bus yesterday! Not to her cell phone nor to the empty pram she'd brought in.

"Love in the Dark" a.k.a. "Love Ethereal", a short story by H. L. Gold first published in Suspense Magazine, Fall 1951, available at the Internet Archive. You may have read it in the 1952 paperback anthology Beyond the End of Time edited by Frederik Pohl or in the 1960 paperback anthology Invisible Men edited by Basil Davenport.
Blue hair and blond eyes:

Long blue hair and wide blond eyes? It must have been a twist of her subvocal tongue. She meant long blond hair and wide blue eyes. Of course.
She closed her eyes and rechecked. The hair was blue and the eyes were blond, or close enough to it. That wasn't all, either. It wasn't really hair. It was feathers. Long, very fine, like bird-of-paradise plumage; but feathers. As long as they were sort of combed flat, she could never have guessed. But her stunning imaginary man frowned as she stared at him, and the frown lifted his—well, feathers, into an attractive crest. Very attractive, in fact. She liked the effect much better than hair. . . .

Invisible baby:

"I know you can't see him," she said, "but I can when I close my eyes. He's a beautiful baby. He has his father's features."

